# php bind parameters in mysqli login not working

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this? Every time it returns with 'login failed' and won't let me pass to the next screen. I'm starting to tare my hair out!!

```
if(!empty($_POST)) { 
        $query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM User WHERE username = ?";
        $sql = $db->prepare($query); 
        $sql->bind_param('s', $user);
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $sql->execute();

        if(!$row = $sql->affected_rows) {   
           print('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']' . gettype($user)); 
        } 

        $login_ok = false; 

        if($row) { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 
            if($check_password === $row['password']) { 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        if($login_ok) { 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 
            header("Location: home.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: home.php"); 
        } else { 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            print("Login Failed. " . $submitted_username);
        } 
    }
```

---

**Update after Comments and Barmars answer**

```
    include '../private/conn.php';
    $submitted_username = ''; 

    if(!empty($_POST)) { 
        $query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM User WHERE username = ?";
        $sql = $db->prepare($query); 
        $sql->bind_param('s', $user);
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $sql->execute();

        $login_ok = false;
        $sql->bind_result($id, $username, $password, $salt);

        if ($sql->fetch()) {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $salt); 
            } 
            if($check_password === $password) { 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        }

        if($login_ok) { 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 
            header("Location: home.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: home.php"); 
        } else { 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            print("Login Failed. " . $submitted_username);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Is the query returning the correct row? Maybe the problem is with how you compare the password.

Comment: You're never calling `$sql->fetch()` to get the row.

Comment: I've only got one row in the table at the moment. All other mysql queries work. The query also works fine if I run it in mysql

Comment: Sidenote: why are you running `affected_rows()` on SELECT? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php *"For SELECT statements mysqli_affected_rows() works like mysqli_num_rows()."*. Unless there's some guru syntax I don't know about.

Comment: Just before `$login_ok = false;` add `print_r($row);` I bet it does not have the values you think it has (where is `$row` filled with values?). See @Barmar's comment (did see it only after having written mine).

Comment: You are hashing for 65536 loops,there`s going to be problems if you have many users

Comment: don't do your own hashing. use bcrypt...

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm fairly new to php and am still learning. I converted this from a pdo mysql example to mysqli.

Comment: your POST arrays all have values? column length's long enough? session was started? just a few things I can think of that could be contributing factors and my *2 cents* here ;-) this in addition to Barmar's answer about not fetching. check for stray spaces too.

Comment: They're all fine. It's worked in the past but moved to using mysqli and I've just had problem after problem with converting this login. I think Barmar is probably correct, but I'm still missing something. I'll update my post with what I've currently got and see if you guys can pick anything else out of it.

Comment: what could help Tom is to add your PDO method that worked for you, and under your edit later on, maybe something relevant to do. Make sure you used the same hashing method also to store it/retrieve. Try http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php also instead of http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: as per your edit, you didn't include `execute()`. and reload my comment up there ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got my login page from this tutorial (I overwrote my version but it was identical) [LINK](http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry deleted the comments and accidentally deleted that line as well. will correct

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've managed to get it working :) using a combination of Barmars answer and part of my original. Thanks to everyone for their help :)

Comment: *hah!* that's great new Tom, glad to hear that your question was solved, *cheers* and you're welcome. (thanks for the update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never calling `$sql->fetch()` to get the row. You're setting `$row` to `$sql->affected_rows`, which returns a number, then you're trying to use it as an associative array. If you had warnings enabled, you would have seen notices about this error.

WHen using a prepared statement, you need to use `bind_result` to get the results into variables, and then call `fetch()` to fetch a row.

```
$sql->bind_result($id, $username, $password, $salt);
if ($sql->fetch()) {
    $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) { 
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $salt); 
    } 
    if($check_password === $password) { 
        $login_ok = true; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's bizarre. Stack's highlighting shows there's a syntax error here, but I can't spot it. After putting it in my editor, it's bracing. Might want to double check that. Edit: it's a quote.

Comment: Still no joy :( I don't know if it's something I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's the apostrophe after the second `$salt`

Comment: Yeah I just saw it now @Tom